# PHP handling Japanese string format

Tags: php, string, formatting, globalization

In my PHP code, I get strings like this one `ＫＡＴＯ １－８２１Ｊ　タキ１０００レタシート`

Is there a PHP function to convert it to a classic string format, i.e. `KATO 1-821J タキ1000レシート`?

I have tried classic functions like `utf8_encode()` but that doesn't work.

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot, didn't now about the mb_convert_kana() function.